# Batch upload images from GCS to Earth Engine assets

Tags: python, google-earth-engine-python-api, batch, google-colab

I have 302 processed Landsat images in GCS and I need to use them in Google Colab. All I've found so far is that you can "bring" those images into Google Colab by copying them into Colab, for example using `!gsutil cp`.

However, I want to make those images into a collection and manipulate them as a collection in Google Colab and in EE. It looks like loading them to EE as an asset is a good solution. I can easily move one image from GCS to EE using earthengine command line `earthegine upload image` and Colab as well but I need to move 302 images, not sure how to accomplish that. Probably doesn't help that I am new to Python.

So far, to upload one image to EE using Colab I've done the following:

```
outputAssetID = 'users/username/landsat_image_name'
outputImageFile = "gs://bucketname/foldername/landsat_image_name.tif"

!earthengine upload image --asset_id={outputAssetID} {outputImageFile}
```

I've thought that perhaps for the outputImageFile variable I could do

```
outputImageFile = 'gs://bucketname/foldername/*.tif
```

But then I'd also need to give a unique name to each Landsat image and probably the command line `upload image` won't like it.

Comment: Did you manage to do it?